# Nginx and PHP working with <?php but not <?

Tags: nginx, php5

I'm trying to configure nginx with shorthand open and close tags.

Currently the following code works for example:

```
<?php include('this.php'); ?>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<? include('this.php'); ?>
```

Is there a way to configure this so it works either way?

Comment: Fix the code. Short open tags are not recommended as they conflict with XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `short_open_tag = On` in php.ini and restart web servers

Answer (score 0):

You must enable open short tag in the php.ini

```
short_open_tag = On
```